# Display imageview onclick and post without imageview if empty

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-intent

I am writing code for a blog app which would post just text or both text and a image below it. I have defined an editText and a imageView in layout. I want that, unless I click on gallery button, the imageview doesn't appear.

I tried that with a intent, but adding activities is making app too heavy.

```
 private ImageButton newPostImgbtn;
 private ImageView newPostImage;
 private EditText newPostDesc;
 private Button newPostBtn;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setTheme(R.style.HomeTheme);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_post);

    newPostImage = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    newPostImgbtn = findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
    newPostDesc = findViewById(R.id.editText);
    newPostBtn = findViewById(R.id.button2);
}
```

I created new activity imageactivity for just adding image by putting an onclick listener on button for gallery newimagebtn, but I don't want to do this in another activity.

```
public void post(View v) { Intent intent = new Intent(postActivity.this, 
imageActivity.class); startActivity(intent);}
```

Also, if the user clicks on the gallery button, but doesn't choose any image, then when post button is clicked, only text appears without a empty imageview area or error because the field is empty. Please help me.

Comment: Please share some more code, its not sufficient to understand

Comment: I did it via intent, should I share code for that? I don't understand code for this problem without intent.

Comment: Yes please share.

Comment: I created new activity imageactivity for just adding image by putting an onclick listener on button for gallery newimagebtn, but I don't want to do this in another activity. Code > public void post(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(postActivity.this, imageActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

Comment: then just use finish() , it will back you your previous activity

Comment: I don't want to add a new activity for something which can be done by a block of if-else statement and throwing exception in the same activity. I have the logic in mind, but I am unable to code it

Comment: Sorry! i am not understand exact what you want

Comment: I want what I put in question and I said there I want to do it without adding any new activity just for image. I want to do it in same activity as for post- text with or without image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In onCreate Method add

```
newPostImgbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                getImageFromAlbum();
            }
        });
```

in your activity class

```
private void getImageFromAlbum(){
    try{
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
    }catch(Exception exp){
        Log.i("Error",exp.toString());
    }
}
```

Add this method to your Activity Class

```
    Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);


            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                try {
                    final Uri imageUri = data.getData();
                    final InputStream imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
                    final Bitmap selectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
                    newPostImage .setImageBitmap(selectedImage);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(PostImage.this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }else {
//image not selected so do what you want when image is not selected      
}
```

Comment: How do I add this image to Imageview 'newPostImage'? I don't have practice with image in androidstudio, where exactly do I learn it?

Comment: Also, thanks a lot for your answer. I upvoted it, but I have 6 reputation only, so my vote isn't displayed.

Comment: I have updated the answer now it will set image on your imageview. 
and if it works please accept the answer. Thanks

Comment: please create a global variable named 
public static int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE =23;

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to take permission from User and open gallery intent. When you found the image url u need show it with image loader library like glide. The last thing you need to do check image url is empty or not when clicked button. Let me know if you need further assistance.

Comment: I don't want to include another library if I can do without it. It will make app heavy. Also I want to do it in the same activity. Please guide a bit with code for this.

Comment: Here is an example of Permission taking without Library
https://gist.github.com/Muhaiminur/9c48ce9ec4554821784bd265bf5af47b